# How to remove the entire line of a word doc using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following line of code will insert text into a bookmark range in a word document.

```
objDoc.Bookmarks("DonorAddress").Range.Text = "6200 Main St."
```

How do I remove the entire line containing the address bookmark if I don't have any address data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By 'deleting the line' I believe you mean to 'delete paragraph'. If so you could do it in this way:

```
'2 steps to delete- rather not recommended
objDoc.Bookmarks("DonorAddress").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
Selection.Delete
```

or in one step:

```
objDoc.Bookmarks("DonorAddress").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
```

Answer (score 3):

If 'deleting the line' means deleting just one line of a paragraph, the following is the way:

```
objDoc.Bookmarks("DonorAddress").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
Selection.HomeKey wdLine
Selection.EndKey wdLine, wdExtend
Selection.Delete
```