# Removing the line where a content control is

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to remove a line where my content control is.

Currently the document has this following text:

```
t1
t2


Status:     Draft
Valid from: 01.01.2012
Valid for:  All Emplyoees

Created by:     a
Released by:    <content control goes here>.
```

I have a variable `controlff` which is a reference to the control. No matter how I get a range from it I always ended up by deleting the full text.

This other questions didn't quite help me:

[Blank line after deleting contentControl in word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450713/blank-line-after-deleting-contentcontrol-in-word)

[How to remove the entire line of a word doc using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112398/how-to-remove-the-entire-line-of-a-word-doc-using-vba)

[deleting certain lines in ms word 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165309/deleting-certain-lines-in-ms-word-2007)

How can I remove the Released by line?

**EDIT**

All the text that I showed before is inside of a single row on a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example how to do this in a table. First get the Content Control, Exctend the selection to the previous line in the table cell and delete the selection.

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range

    'Get your Content Control here based on your variable reference
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range

    rng.Select

    'Move outside the Content Control
    Selection.MoveRight wdCharacter
    Selection.MoveRight wdCharacter

    'Select Line Up
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend

    'Include the paragraph from previous line
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend

    'And ... Delete the selected area
    Selection.Delete
End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Is your Content Control in a Table? I tested the code with the text you provided, inserted a CC at the placeholder and worked without issues. So there must be something in your text that prohibits expanding the Range.

Comment: Changed it to work with a CC in a table ... can you try again?

Comment: That approach deletes the whole text on the row. All the text that I showed on my question is inside the same row unfortantly (and I can't really do anything about that) . I would like to delete only the last line on the row.

Comment: ooohhh ... well you need to be more precise on what your scenario is. This means putting in -all- information that is relevant to the question. I've inserted two valid solutions already but you keep coming up with new information! I'll try and see if I can find time to get this one too.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort Marteen but it's not like I didn't give that information, after all I placed the text in the same block. SO shouldn't be the place where others solve the problems for you but I would gladly receive more input from you. Anyway maybe I can try to proceed from this, even if it takes much longer than you would.

Comment: Aannnnd.... changed again, now to address deleting only the last line in the Table Cell where the Content Control was found. It's a bit of a pain, finding the exact movements but I think you can find it for your specific format if you experiment a bit with the selection based on my example.